# Jquery Mobile - how to change the height of listview

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

To change the height of listView I have used this :

```
.ui-li .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li {
             padding-top:10px;
             padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

This make every listView height changed.Okay, everything is fine.But it also change the height of the pop-up option list value of select field.[image: Height becomes tinny]

I can add internal CSS to fix it but this needs a lot of page to be proccessed.Now I want to know Is there any way to write better non-overriding CSS for both listview and select menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the height of the listview while not overriding it:

- You should find the source of the class that is causing it.
- Remove the class with jquery
- replace it with your own class

**To replace class**

```
$("p").removeClass(".ui-li .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li ").addClass(".whatever .your .class .is");
```

You have to be detailed and specific.

Comment: It is a hack.Not a proper solution.Thanks :)